# Selenium WebDriver java.lang.NullPointerExceoption

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have used this method in the past but I haven't done much with selenium recently. I'm trying to setup this test to have multiple cases that run in order.

Here is my code

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import java.time.Duration;

public class TotalAutomatation {

static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass public static void setup() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\con15096\\snow_demo\\autotile\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://nk.okta.com/login/login.htmfromURI=%2Fapp%2Fservicenow_app2%2Fexkbcm77encfzK3a80x7%2Fsso%2Fsaml%3FSAMLRequest%3DnVJdb5swFP0ryO9gMGkhVojEEk2L1nWoyfqwl8mBS2vF2MzX0Ky%252FfsTJ1O5hVbVH2%252Beej3u8QNEp1vNycI%252F6Dn4OgC44dkojP78UZLCaG4ESuRYdIHc135ZfbjiLYt5b40xtFAlKRLBOGr0yGocO7BbsKGv4dndTkEfneuSUYi%252BtdEJaJTVgA2OEZ1SozVNUm45qMfbiAaLGkGA9eZFanEhfKPQhMgcnPFj0Pb0QTPM%252FpiOjcDzs6y7LQNft8%252BdU5PExo4iGnuKQ4KOxNfiwBWmFQiDBZl2Q7e2qnWe1SK%252FZ1fwaGtam6TxncTtvr6DJ9yzJJiBWAlGO8DKKOMBGoxPaFYTFSR7GecjSXRzz2YzPkihm6XcSVJc1fZC6kfrh7Z3uzyDkn3a7Kqy%252BbneeYJQN2NsJ%252Fb%252FrvAeLfpWTCFkufL3cJ7CvG3%252FbnPhTM1m%252B28WCvta6KPf8lGWzroyS9a%252BgVMo8rSwIN%252BVzdgBfVSfcv%252B0kUeJvZBO2HsqhE1KVTWMBkdDlRffvz738DQ%253D%253D%26RelayState%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fspiritairlinesdev.service-now.com%252Fsolveit%253Fid%253Dsolveit_dept_dev");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("okta-signin-username")).sendKeys("username");
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    driver.findElement(By.id("okta-signin-password")).sendKeys("password");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("okta-signin-submit")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.get("https://spiritairlinesdev.service-now.com/solveit");
}

@Test public  void getFirstTile1() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"xd150fd31cb10020000f8d856634c9ce6\"]/li[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    Select dropList = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("edit_tile_level")));
    dropList.selectByVisibleText("FlightOPS/ Inflight");
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    dropList.selectByVisibleText("Submit a New Request");
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    dropList.selectByVisibleText("System Access Request");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement TemplateCard = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"template_color\"]"));
    WebElement card1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"02844eecdb486700433c38ff9d961914_color\"]"));
    new Actions(driver)
            .moveToElement(card1)
            .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .clickAndHold(card1)
            .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .moveToElement(TemplateCard)
            .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .release().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("I have the first tile");
    driver.findElement(By.id("previous_parent")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    driver.findElement(By.id("previous_parent")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    driver.findElement(By.id("previous_parent")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    dropList.selectByVisibleText("Airport Stations");
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    dropList.selectByVisibleText("Submit a New Request");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    dropList.selectByVisibleText("System Access Request");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("save_new_tile")).click();

}

@AfterClass public static void closeWindow() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    driver.close();
}
```

}

It runs the @BeforeTest case but fails when it tries to go into the first @Test

I'm having trouble understanding why it breaks after the @BeforeClass.

Comment: Which line throws the  nullreferenceexception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

you create a method local variable. So the static field is never written.

Just remove `WebDriver` so you actually access the static field.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TotalAutomatation {

// This is global variable
// this variable is declared but not initialized
static WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeClass 
     // I am happy at compile time and run time as I can 
     // access local variable which is declared and initialized both
   public static void setup() throws InterruptedException {

    // this is local variable with same name
    // this variable is declared and initialized also
    // I have overridden driver value for BeforeClass
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

} // scope ended here for local variable

@Test 
 // I am not happy at run time as I have access to global variable
 // which is only declared but not initialized
public void getFirstTile1() throws InterruptedException {
 // here at run time global variable will be accessed which 
 // is static variable which and it is null :(
 // My next statement will suffer NullPointerException :-(
driver.findElement();
}
```

Comment: global,local,run time,compile time,initialization,declaration all are written correctly still -1 motivates me to write very limited answer